# Disable typescript compilation in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I am running grunt and have set up a typescript build process that listens for file changes, therefore I don't need the default VS compilation of my typescript files when I save or build my project.

I have unchecked the 'Compile on save' option under typescript in my project properties, but the ts files are still being compiled. The only way this works for me is if I set the build action of individual TS files to 'None', but this is still causing some Typescript files to be compiled. Is there any way this can be done in VS2013?

Comment: Do you get a solution for this? Having the same problem currently.

Comment: Hi xvdiff. As mentioned above, uncheck the 'compile on save' option under typescript in my project properties and then set the build action of the ts files to 'none'. A bit tedious I  know, but that's the only way I have got it to work.

Comment: Make sure you don't have Web Essentials or similar extension that could be compiling on build.

Answer (score 15):

In VS2015, a `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` setting can be added to the first `<PropertyGroup>` element in .csproj

msbuild output should then show

```
PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
  TypeScript compile is skipped because the TypeScriptCompileBlocked property is set to true.
```

From: http://rostacik.net/2015/08/14/how-to-disable-building-of-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: For my VS2015 asp.net core RC2 project (which did not have a .csproj file), adding <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> to the .xproj (not .csproj) file stopped the typescript compilation that happens when I PUBLISH my project.  Typescript already did not compile on save during development because I added a tsconfig.json (without "compileOnSave": true) to my project.  I use gulp to compile for my workflow. But In my case <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> was needed to suppress compilation during publishing of my project.  I'm using Typescript 1.8.9.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and solution that I found is to override TypeScript targets in the VS project file:

```
<Target Name="PreComputeCompileTypeScript">
  <Message Text="Skipping PreComputeCompileTypeScript" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CompileTypeScript">
  <Message Text="Skipping CompileTypeScript" />
</Target>
<Target Name="GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems">
  <Message Text="Skipping GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Christopher Mott answer works also for Visual Studio 2013, at least for **Update 5** and **TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 1.8.5.0**. To be sure, one could verify if VS TypeScript toolchain *understands* that flag:

Open `.csproj` file for the intendend project and notice that it imports TypeScript targets from some:

> $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets

that generally maps to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<your VS version number>\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets

Inspect that file and look for `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` being defined (as false) in some `<PropertyGroup>`. If it's there, you're sorted. Go back to `.csproj` file and add the following, right after where TypeScript targets are imported:

```xml
<!-- Disable TypeScript compilation from within VS, leave that to external tools -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score -3):

Change the `Build Action` property on your TypeScript files to something other than `TypeScript Compile`